# Parsing the xml file independent of tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to parse the xml file independent of the tags .So the code for the parsing should become generic one. Is there any way to do this in iPhone which is flexible with tags. I have tried to solve this problem by parsing the xml two times.In first parse i have extracted tags only and in second pass i tried to find the value of that tag. But there was the problems with this approach . So is there any api or logic to parse xml independent of tags? is it really possible?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS there is no existing API or logic for parsing xml files with unknown tags. To parse xml you need to know tags of that xml.

Comment: :If i parse the xml two times .in first pass i will get the element names which can be stored into the array in second pass i can extract the string corresponding to this element . But problem is how to create a generic class ?

Comment: Do you want to create a generic class which will contain xml-parsed data?

Comment: Yes,that class should capable to store whatever data in the xml file as a object format.

Comment: You can't create classes in runtime. To create a class you need to describe it to your app in compile and build time. So, it seems to me, that your idea is impossible to achieve. :(

Comment: and if i created a class with id as a data type for all its data member ? is there any possibility?

Comment: You don't even know how many data members there will be. And I am not sure that you will be able to parse correctly nested tags for complicated xml's. And moreover - you will still need to know tag names outside of your generic class to work with xml data.